# How to execute event from another event?

Tags: .net, events, datagridview

I have a datagridview bound to Table. Table's columns are IDTransaction Amount TransactionType.

I want to change color of Amount cells based on TransactionType.

```
if (transactiontype==1) 
    cell.backgroundcolor=red;
else
    cell.backgroundcolor=white;
```

Where do you recommend to me to do it?(In which event)

Thank you

Comment: you need to provide lot more context, is it ASP.NET or WinForms, how you are binding? are there any binding events you are already handling? you are asking for recommendation, so you should give out all the criteria to recommend on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows Forms you would typically put this code in the [CellFormatting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

 if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name = "TransactionType")
 {

    if (e.Value != null)
    {
        if (e.Value == 1)
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
         }
     }
  }
}
```